# Xamarin Forms Registering Customer Services with Unity for View Model Constructors

Tags: c#, unity-container, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to inject a service into a ViewModel when it's navigated to. Despite the reference I've looked at on Brian Lagunas's blog, sample code, etc, something doesn't seem to be right.

Given in my **App.cs**

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void OnInitialized ()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync ("SignInPage", animated: false);
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes ()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SignInPage>();
        Container.RegisterType<IUserAuthentication, UserAuthenticationService>();
    }
```

}

Note: the `using` statements for the IUserAuthentication and UserAuthenticationService namespaces are in place.

**SignInPageViewModel.cs**

```
private INavigationService _navigationService;
private IUserAuthentication _userAuthenticationService;

public SignInPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IUserAuthentication userAuthenticationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _userAuthenticationService = userAuthenticationService;
}
```

`Container.RegisterType` doesn't seem to accept the generic. All the examples I've seen with Unity seem to support it but I get the following error.

```
The non-generic method 'IUnityContainer.RegisterType(Type, Type, string, LifetimeManager, params InjectionMember[])' cannot be used with type arguments
```

It's a build error.

Package Info

- Using Prism.Unity.Forms v6.2.0-pre5
- Prism.Forms v6.1.0-pre5
- Prism.Core 6.1.0
- Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.46-pre3
- Unity 4.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The generic version of `RegisterType` is an extension method and resides in the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace. To use it, either call it explicitly

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<ISomething, SomeService>( Container );
```

or add

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
```

Comment: Gah! Thank you. Still new to .NET. I thought (wrongly) that Prism's Unity extensions would be pulling the rest of the Unity stuff in.

Sometimes finding which using statements I want is the most challenging bit.

Answer (score -1):

you need the using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

Comment: Take a moment to read [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  As it stands this answer is almost utterly useless.